# Updating DE through SmartCapture in CloudPage

Tags: marketing-cloud, ampscript, dataextensions, cloudpage, smart-capture

Consider a scenario where a mail will be sent to contacts in Data Extension. The mail contains a button that will redirect to CloudPage.

This cloud page has a smart capture that will prepopulate some fields like EmpId, FirstName, LastName in text fields from contacts in DE and there are Other input fields where the user will enter Data to input fields and click the submit button.

After hitting the submit button the cloud page, Contact in DE gets updated by adding newly entered data by the user.

My problem in this scenario is how to update the contact in DE. smart capture is unable to update because it is trying to add the record in DE but EmpId(Primary Key) already exists in DE.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly, the to answer your question **Currently the SMART CAPTURE is ADD ONLY!** hence you cannot perform UPDATE operations via SMART capture.

According to me, the best solution is to hand code a cloud page to achieve your requirement, by simple AMPscript functions. Below site by @Eliot Harper would definitely would help

> **AMPscript guide:** https://ampscript.guide/

However, if you wish to go through the current technique only, then you may have to chose the work around as below.

1) [Upsert/Add to data extension using Smart Capture](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/251516/upsert-add-to-data-extension-using-smart-capture)

2) https://success.salesforce.com/answers?id=9063A000000e7rOQAQ